# How to disable the pinch-zoom gesture on Windows8 laptops

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I am developing a Windows 8 desktop application using C#, JavaScript, and HTML5. In the C# level I am using the WebView object.

I want to disable the pinch-zoom in my application. I know how to do it in HTML:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

When I run the HTML page as *standalone* it's working (I pasted the URL into the Internet Explorer). But when I run the whole application it doesn't work - the pinch-zoom is enabled, and not disabled.

B.T.W: I am using Internet Explorer 10.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

In IE10 (and soon other browsers), the easiest way to prevent touch pinch zoom in HTML/CSS/JS is to use the touch-action CSS property (vendor prefixed in IE10). The default value is "auto", which includes panning, pinch zoom, and double tap zoom by default in IE10. You can override with just the touch behaviors that you want enabled:

```
html {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y; /* Enables only panning */
}
```

For more, see the W3C Standard for Pointer Events: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/#declaring-candidate-regions-for-default-touch-behaviors