# Disable Zoom in x-ms-webview HTML Control (Win 8.1) with Javascript (not by css content)

Tags: javascript, html, webview, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

how can I disable in a **Windows 8.1** App with the **x-ms-webview** (HTML/JS) the Pinch/Zoom?

The **iframe** did not have the zoom. But in in 8.1 you can't use HTTP anymore with iframe.

Microsoft removed HTTP for IFRAME but don't added the same functionality to the **x-ms-webview**.

I've checked with http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/17/what-s-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1.aspx and the API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx apply CSS like here to the content of the webview like here [How to disable the pinch-zoom gesture on Windows8 laptops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592846/how-to-disable-the-pinch-zoom-gesture-on-windows8-laptops).... but no luck.

I have no influence on the Content of the HTTP Urls used in the x-ms-webview. So can't just add the CSS Tag to the Pages navigated to.

I found no Event Listener on the x-ms-webview to intercept the **ms-touch-action** and prevent the zoom.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your wrapper-app's CSS:

```
* {
  -ms-content-zooming: none;
}
```